# Metrics Collector with Kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I'll try to make a non-broad question:

I have a microservices infrastructure at my application. I want to collect some metrics at my application. Some of services are producers, some of them are consumers and some of them are both.

I want to use Kafka but I haven't used to before. What I want to do is:

1. Some producers will send some numbers (e.g. 1)
2. Metrics Collector will collect those numbers
3. When a consumer makes a request it will get average (or something else) of that numbers

I know that I can use:

```
ProducerRecord<String, Integer>
```

I use Spring Boot and can use its current integration:

https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/15/using-apache-kafka-for-integration-and-data-processing-pipelines-with-spring

or a native Kafka implementation.